# Ngrx get Item from store State: Type 'Item[]' is missing the following properties

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I would like to get My store state of Items, but I'm getting an error "not assignable"

**ItemReducer**

```
export const initState: Item[] = [...];

export function ItemReducer(state = initState, action: ActionParent) {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**ItemListComponent**

```
export class myItemsComponent implements OnInit {

  myItems: Observable<Item[]>;

  constructor(private store: Store<{ items: Item[] }>) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store
      .select('items')
      .subscribe((data: Item[]) => (this.myItems = data)); // error here
  }
}
```

so I have an error like:

```
Type 'Item[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Item[]>'.ts(2322)
Type 'Item[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<Item[]>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 5 more.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myItems` is an Observable. Please remove the subscription or change the type of `myItems`. Removing the subscription (use async pipe) should be the preferred way.

Remove subscription way

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myItems = this.store.select('items');
  }
```

Change type way

```
myItems: Item[];
```

Comment: but If I remove "subscribe" on ngOnInit if I decide to console.log(this.mapItems) I can't see the Items on console.

Comment: Yes because this is an observable. You could add an tap operator in case you want to additionally print it.

Answer (score 0):

You defined `myItems` as observables, but you are assigning data with type `Item[]` to it.
change `myItem` type to `Item[]`:

```
  myItems: Item[];
```